# Installed python3, getting command not found error in terminal

Tags: python, macos, path

I installed python3, I can open idle and it says it is running python3.0.1, but when I enter python3 in the terminal (on OSX) I get an error saying 'command not found'. Entering python gets me the 2.x version that came on the computer. Any advice on how I can access python3 from the terminal?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried calling it from its install location?

Comment: If it works from the installation directory it's probably a path problem, path as in your environment variables, not sure how to edit them on OSX, if your 2.x version runs fine it's probably pointing to that directory instead of the 3.0.1-directory.

Comment: @I agree with @dutt. If you were on windows, I could give you detailed instructions, as I've solved this issue a bunch of times. Essentially, the list of paths your system checks lists the python2x directory before the python3 directory. SuperUser may be able to give you better assistance.

Answer (score 16):

First, don't use Python 3.0.1.  It has many problems and was officially retired upon the release of Python 3.1 (currently 3.1.2).  You can find the python.org Mac OS X installer for 3.1.2 [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.1.2/).  Once it is installed, then you need to ensure that the `bin` directory from the 3.1.2 framework (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin`) is on your shell search path.  You can manually modify an appropriate shell startup file, like `.bash_profile`.  Or just double-click the `Update Shell Profile.command` found in `/Applications/Python 3.1`.  In either case, you will need to open a new terminal window or re-login.  Another approach is to install Python 3.1 from `MacPorts` or another distributor.  Also, alpha releases of Python 3.2 are now available from python.org and elsewhere.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  By the way, when you post a question on Stackoverflow, you should either mark an answer as accepted (so that the answerer gets reputation points) or edit your question until you do get a satisfactory answer.