# Installed python 3, bash does not recognize python3 command

Tags: python, git-bash

I'm having troubles getting python 3 to work in my bash shell. I have installed both python2 and python3 on my PC (Windows 10). When I type `python --version` in the bash terminal it prints `Python 2.7.13`, but when I type `python3 --version` it prints: bash: `python3: command not found`. I can't find `Update Shell Profile.command` file as suggested in [Installed python3, getting command not found error in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895756/installed-python3-getting-command-not-found-error-in-terminal)

Comment: Clearly something wrong with your environment variables. Are you running on windows or a *nix system?

Comment: Tried using the exact version? Like python3.5

Comment: I'm running it on windows

Comment: If you do not want/need python2 on path just replace the py2 routes on your path for the py3 ones. See: [Setting environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables)